# What is different between array String and common array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, memory

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[7];
    scanf("%s",&str);

    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        printf("%x(%d) : %c\n",&str[i], &str[i], str[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n%x(%d) : %c      or    %s",&str, &str, str, str);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm confused about pointer of C Array because of Array with String.

Actually I want to save each character for single line input.

It is worked but I found something strange...

The main issue is **&str** and **&str[0]** have same address value.

But **str** have String Value with %s..

**str[0]** have Char Value with %c..

I used **str** with %c then it has first two numbers of **str**'s address.

What is going on in Array..?

Where is real address for Stirng value??

And how can **scanf("%s",&str)** distribute String to each char array space?

```
Input : 123456789
62fe40(6487616) : 1
62fe41(6487617) : 2
62fe42(6487618) : 3
62fe43(6487619) : 4
62fe44(6487620) : 5
62fe45(6487621) : 6
62fe46(6487622) : 7

62fe40(6487616) : @    123456789
```

This is result window of my code.

Comment: Your questions are great since they show exactly what you already know and need to know. To make it perfect, could you please [edit] your question and replace the image with the actual text from the image? That makes it easier to read for us.

Comment: Oh I can't thing about that. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Your scanf is writing the characters to memory one by one, from the start address given, but since you have only reserved a 7 byte buffer your program now overwrite other parts of the memory it should not have touched. This is a very common source of security problems -  buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is different between array String and common array in C?

An *array* is a contiguous sequence of objects of one type.<sup>1</sup>

A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by the first null character.<sup>2</sup> So a string is simply an array of characters where we mark the end by putting a character with value zero. (Often, strings are temporarily held in larger arrays that have more elements after the null character.)

So every string is an array. A string is simply an array with two extra properties: Its elements are characters, and a zero marks the end.

> **&str** and **&str[0]** have same address value.

`&str` is the address of the array. `&str[0]` is the address of the first element.

These are the same place in memory, because the first element starts in the same place the array does. So, when you print them or examine them, they will often appear the same. (Addresses can have different representations, the same way you might write “200” or “two hundred” or “2•10<sup>2</sup>” for the same number. So the same address might sometimes look different. In most modern systems, an address is just a simple number for a place in memory, and you will not see differences. But it can happen.)

> `printf("%x(%d) : %c\n",&str[i], &str[i], str[i]);`

This is not a correct way to print addresses. To print an address properly, convert it to `void *` and use `%p`<sup>3</sup>:

```
printf("%p(%p) : %c\n", (void *) &str[i], (void *) &str[i], str[i]);
```

> `printf("\n\n%x(%d) : %c      or    %s",&str, &str, str, str);`
>
> …
>
> I used **str** with %c then it has first two numbers of **str**'s address.

In the above `printf`, the third conversion specification is `%c`, and the corresponding argument is `str`. `%c` is intended to be used for a character,<sup>4</sup> but you are passing it an argument that is a pointer. What may have happened here is that `printf` used the pointer you passed it as if it were an `int`. Then `printf` may have used a part of that `int` as if it were a character and printed that. So you saw part of the address shown as a character. However, it is a bit unclear when you write “it has the first two numbers of **str**'s address”. You could show the exact output to clarify that.

Although `printf` may have used the pointer as if it were an `int`, the behavior for this is not defined by the C standard. Passing the wrong type for a `printf` conversion is improper, and other results can occur, including the program printing garbage or crashing.

> And how can **scanf("%s",&str)** distribute String to each char array space?

The proper way to pass `str` to `scanf` for `%s` is to pass the address of the first character, `&str[0]`. C has a special rule for arrays like `str`: If an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or the address-of operator `&`, it is converted to a pointer to its first element.<sup>5</sup> So, you can use `scanf("%s", str)`, and it will be the same as `scanf("%s", &str[0])`.

However, when you use `scanf("%s",&str)`, you are passing the address of the array instead of the address of the first character. Although these are the same location, they are different types. Recall that two different types of pointers to the same address might have different representations. Because `scanf` does not have knowledge of the actual argument type you pass it, it must rely on the conversion specifier. `%s` tells `scanf` to expect a pointer to a character.<sup>6</sup> Passing it a pointer to an array is improper.

C has this rule because some machines have different types of pointers, and some systems might pass different types of pointers in different ways. Nonetheless, often code that passes `&str` instead of `str` behaves as the author desired because the C implementation uses the same representation for both pointers. So `scanf` may actually receive the pointer value that it needs to make `%s` work.<sup>7</sup>

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> C 2018 6.2.5 20. (This means the information comes from the 2018 version of the C standard, ISO/IEC 9899, *Information technology—Programming Languages—C*, clause 6.2.5, paragraph 20.)

<sup>2</sup> C 2018 7.1.1 1. Note that the terminating null character is considered to be a part of the string, although it is not counted by the `strlen` function.

<sup>3</sup> C 2018 7.21.6.1 8.

<sup>4</sup>  Technically, the argument should have type `int`, and `printf` converts it to `unsigned char` and prints the character with that code. C 2018 7.21.6.1 8.

<sup>5</sup> C 2018 6.3.2.1 3. A string literal used to initialize an array, as in `char x[] = "Hello";`, is also not converted to a pointer.

<sup>6</sup> C 2018 7.21.6.2 12.

<sup>7</sup> Even if a C implementation uses the same representations for different types of pointers, that does not guarantee that using one pointer type where another is required will work. When a compiler optimizes a program, it relies on the program’s author having obeyed the rules, and the optimizations may change the program in ways that would not break a program that followed the rules but that do break a program that breaks the rules.

Comment: So much clearer than anything else I have come across so far. +1

Answer (score 2):

You are confused because the string and the array are the same thing. - In the memory there are only data (and pointers to that data)

When you allocate an integer or a buffer for a string you reserve some of this memory. Strings in c is defined as a sequence of bytes terminated by one byte with the value 0 - The length is not known. With the fix length array you have a known size to work with.

The real value to the string is the pointer to the first character.

When you print with %c it expects a char - str[0] not the pointer - When you print with %s it expects a pointer to a sequence of chars.

```
printf("\n\n%x(%d) : %c      or    %s",&str, &str, str[0], str);
```

Comment: Now I understand about this! Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: `In the memory there are only data (and pointers to that data)` there are no pointers to the data in the memory. Same misunderstanding as @hat

Answer (score 0):

`String` is only some kind of the shorthand of the `zero terminated char array`. So there is no difference between the `string` and the "normal" array.

> Where is real address for Stirng value??

Arrays are not pointers and they only decay to pointers. So **there is no** physical space in the memory where the address of the first element of the array is stored.

> The main issue is &str and &str[0] have same address value.

It is not the issue - array is the chunk of memory. So the address of this chunk is the same as the address of its first element. The **types** are different.